# Reactstrap's col-0 doesn't work as expected in NextJS 12

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-bootstrap, reactstrap

Just installed NextJS 12 and I'm working on a small app but when I want to use a Col with a 0 size it doesn't work as expected, here is my JSX code :

```
<Container>
  <Row>
      <Col xs="0">hello</Col>
    <Col>world</Col>
  </Row>
</Container>
```

here is the result I get :

[image]

here is my dependencies :

[image]

here is my imports :

[image]

here is the CSS generated for the inspected element :

[image]

I cant figure out if it's a bug in some library or a mistake by me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in the bootstrap 5 package, For now I have found a solution by downgrading the bootstrap version from 5 to 4.1

For yarn :

```
yarn add bootstrap@4.1
```

For NPM :

```
npm i bootstrap@4.1
```